# Database relations & OOP - Egg and chicken problem

Tags: java, oop, orm, mapping, relational-database

These are my tables:

```
users
-----------------
| id | username |
-----------------
| 1  | stepha.. |
| 2  |  sophia  |
-----------------

projects
---------------------------------------
| id | author_id | name | description |
---------------------------------------
| 1  |     1     | Th.. | A list of.. |
| 2  |     1     | Fo.. | Some of S.. |
| 3  |     1     | A .. | Just some.. |
| 4  |     2     | Wh.. | Gladly be.. |
| 5  |     2     | In.. | Whenever .. |
| 6  |     1     | Th.. | These are.. |
---------------------------------------

tasks
----------------------------
| id | project_id |  name  |
----------------------------
| 1  |     2      |  null  |
| 2  |     2      |  null  |
| 3  |     1      |  null  |
----------------------------
```

I have (some) classes that look like this:

```
Project
- long id
- User author
- String name
- String description
- List<Task> tasks
+ ... (Getters/Setters)

Task
- long id
- Project project
- String name
+ ... (Getters/Setters)
```

Now, how can I map the data from the database, so a Project object can contain a list of tasks, while a Task object refers to its own Project object?

`List<Task> tasks = task.getProject().getTasks()`

It gets a bit crazy when having to store these values in persistent storage. Fetching data from the ProjectMapper will return a Project object. But now that object needs to contain tasks, which needs reference the project?

I've considered just storing their ids, like in the database. But that doesn't seem very object oriented and leads to a relational structure similar to database's (which kinda misses the point of mapping)

I've also considered NOT referencing the project in the Task object, though that leads to issues where the project needs to be known when inserting into the tasks table. Should the method just look like this `taskMapper.insert(Project project)` instead of this `taskMapper.insert(Task task)` ? It seems overkill to parse an entire project just for its id, and what does projects have to do in the TaskMapper class anyways?

I'm confused, and surely this is not the first time someone has been a problem like this. I haven't been able to find much searching on Google though. Hope some of you have a best practice approach to something like this. I'm willing to refactor all of it, if it means getting rid the distasteful soup I've made. Yuck!

Comment: Have a look at JPA and its entity relationships. Such a data-structure is common and actually easy to implement compared to more complex relationships. Do you already have an ORM in your project? What is your tech-stack?